# Updating the view of an item from a CollectionView

Tags: chaplinjs

I'm trying to update the view of an item belonging to a CollectionView. 
The best way should call "render()" from that particular view? 
Despite the model change
I think I'm missing something important here, because, although the model has changed, calling "render()", does not update the view.
Thanks for your help!
Regards!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to call "render()" is to subscribe CollectionView to some event for example "update_collection_view". Read more on [Chaplin.mediator](http://docs.chaplinjs.org/chaplin.mediator.html). This is common chaplin mechanism to communicate and exchange information, this prevent memory leaks. Often event raises in "fetch()" method of collection or model after loading data from server.

```
define [
'chaplin'
'views/base/view'
'views/base/collection_view'
], (Chaplin, View, CollectionView) ->


class SomeView extends View
  template: template1
  template = null
  foo: ->
    #here we update collection view
    Chaplin.mediator.publish 'update_collection_view'



class SomeCollectionView extends CollectionView
  itemView: SomeView

  template: template2
  template = null

  initialize: ->
    super
    @subscribeEvent 'update_collection_view', @render
```